# Url or url path replace

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, proxy

I want ask is that possible code "url replacer" basiclly its like proxy. You just run it and it replace specific url for example: `https://cliquant.lol` to `https://cliquant.ml`

*its something like fiddler 'autoresponder'*

Comment: Please, **pick one language**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AjaxHook for this. https://github.com/wendux/ajax-hook

Here is a code I wrote, that replaces data from `google.com` to something you can set, however, you need something like `Tempermonkey` to run this when the website loads, since our hook needs to run before the website makes new request.

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * List of all our proxy functions.
     * @type {[{response: (function(*): *), url: string}]}
     */
    const proxies = [
        {
            url: 'https://google.com',
            response: (response) => {

                //Modify the response data and return it.
                response.data = {
                    ...
                }
                return response;
            }
        },

    ]

    /**
     * Attach the AjaxHook to the XMLHttpRequest object.
     */
    ah.proxy({
        onRequest: (config, handler) => {
            const url = config.url;

            const proxy = proxies.find(proxy => url.includes(proxy.url));
            if (proxy && proxy.request) {
                config = proxy.request(config, handler);
            }

            handler.next(config);
        },
        onResponse: (response, handler) => {
            const config = response.config;
            const url = config.url;
            const proxy = proxies.find(proxy => url.includes(proxy.url));

            if (proxy && proxy.response) {
                response.response = JSON.stringify(proxy.response(JSON.parse(response.response), handler));
            }

            handler.next(response)
        }
    })
})();
```